# define return value for java method in native file in android native app

Tags: android, java-native-interface, return, native

In define findclass and getmethodid in Android native app, I have an method that returns a value of Uri.

below is my native code:

```
void Java_com_example_myapp_MainActivity_callnative(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj){
    jclass handlerClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/example/myapp/myclass");
     jmethodID parsemethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, handlerClass, "methodname", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/net/Uri"); 

}
```

MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static String LIB_NAME = "nativelib";

    static {
        System.loadLibrary(LIB_NAME);
    }
     
    public native void callnative();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        callnative();
    }
}
```

and myclass code which has a method(show) and Native code will call this method:

```
   public class myclass {
        
         public Uri show(Uri Uri)
         {
             Log.v("called from native", "calling from native side");
            return Uri.parse("content://this/string");
         }  
    }
```

I get this error:
Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name ="methodname" signature=' (Ljava/lang/String;) Landroid/net/Uri' in class Lcom/example/myapp/myclass;

suppose this is for Define Return value,
for return value like Void we set Only V, but I do not have any idea about Uri.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you are probably calling the native method from the `java` `static` method, just remove key word `static` From your `MainActivity`

Comment: jclass handlerClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "com/example/calljavaservice/DataBaseService");
 jmethodID parsemethod = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, handlerClass, "show", "(Landroid/net/Uri;)URI");
here is my MainActivity class:

Comment: edit your original question and add the code to it! you can't enter more than 600 characters in a comment !!!!!!!!!1

Comment: remove static keyword from your main activity ! as mentioned above in my answer

Comment: i get that error again :(
when i change the return value to Void and set only V everything is Ok

Comment: Mr Alsanie, Do you know how can I define  java methods return values like Uri or something other than V or String?

Comment: yes you can simply change the return type of the method and it would work.
did it work "Removing static keyword"?

Comment: When method return value is Void or String, everything is Ok ,either using Static or not Static keyword, I have fixed that Mr Alsanie, excuse me i need load this codes in Native file also:
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
     Cursor cursor2;
 Uri uri=Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");cursor2 = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
but i dont have any idea how define findclass and getmethodID and ... :(